# grunt.file.expand glob for grabbing .gitkeep file

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I'm grabbing the contents of a folder using grunt.file.expand and in the chained forEach any file with .gitkeep, .gitattribute, etc are not picked up in the **/* globbing pattern.  How do you grab these types of named files in a globbing pattern using grunt?  Throws error that says in /commands, which is just one of the folders that contains a .gitkeep file (also only file in the folder).

```
"Unable to read bower\components\project\app\commands file"
```

Code snippet:

```
// Return unique array of all file paths, which match globbing pattern
var options = {
    cwd: srcPath
};

var globPatterns = ['app/**/*', 
                    'bootstrap/**/*', 
                    'public/**/*']

grunt.file.expand( options, globPatterns ).forEach( function ( srcPathRelCwd ) {

    // Copy a source file to a destination path, creating directories if necessary
    grunt.file.copy(

        // Node API join to keep this cross-platform
        path.join( srcPath, srcPathRelCwd ),
        path.join( destPath, srcPathRelCwd )
    );
} );
```

**UPDATE:**

Added filter to options, which jumps me over the error, but some folders don't get created with files in them, such as the /app/commands with the .gitkeep file in it.

```
// Return unique array of all file paths, which match globbing pattern
var options = {
    cwd: srcPath,
    filter: 'isFile'
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh, was in front of my face the whole time, this is like looking for ketchup in a fridge full of ketchup, damn these man eyes.  Hopefully my wife can't see this...

```
// Return unique array of all file paths, which match globbing pattern
var options = {
    cwd: srcPath,
    filter: 'isFile',
    dot: true // include .files even if not in globbing pattern
};
```